# How can I annotate a MySQLConnection in python?

Tags: python, annotations, mysql-connector

I am using the mysql.connect library.
I'd like to have a function that returns a connection and a cursor, but trying to annotate it always leads to errors like 'MySQLConnection is not defined'.

```py
  cnx: MySQLConnection = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='toor', host='127.0.0.1')
  # "MySQLConnection" is not defined
```

How am I supposed to annotate this ?

Comment: How can I mark this as answered ?

Comment: You need to write an answer yourself and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Fill in the "Your Answer" textarea below and then click "Post Your Answer" button.  Note that `from some_module import *` [is not considered to be good style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/5320906).  `from some_module import SomeSpecificName` would be better.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.cursor import CursorBase
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.